# Send gzip through http cilent

Tags: android, gzip, httpclient

I am making post call in below way.

```
      HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        int timeoutConnection = 3000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                timeoutConnection);
        int timeoutSocket = 5000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        ResponseHandler<String> resonseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(url);
        // JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        // json.put("id", data);
        postMethod.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        postMethod.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(data.getBytes("UTF8")));
        response = httpClient.execute(postMethod, resonseHandler);
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Connector response:" + response);
```

But I want to send **gzip**   , how I can do it ?
I know we can add this:

`postMethod.setHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");`

But how to make string to **gzip** and send?

Comment: Use `application/octet-stream` instead of `application/json`.

Comment: MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
   entity.addPart("?", new ByteArrayBody(fooGzippedBytes,
     "?")); what should i add where i have put ?